# Multiple TransChoice Usage

Tags: symfony, twig, translate

I have a useage for transchoice where I need to translate a string for multiple items in the string.  As a simplied example, I want to translate a string about the number fruit that I have in stock.  At the moment I can do:

```
translate.string: '{0}No fruit|{1}One piece of fruit|]1.Inf[%count% pieces of fruit'
```

in my yaml translate file, then translate as 
`{{ 'translate.string|transchoice(5) }}` 
in twig.  All good.

But how can I do this when I separate out the fruit by type, and wish to translate for bananas, oranges, grapes and apples.  At the moment I see only a possiblity of only one of the types being given to the transchoice, and the rest as parameters.  Has anyone seen a translation for multiple transchoice in a single translation string.  I do have a solution for this issue, but wish to see any other solutions that may improve on my solution.

I have overridden the Synfony Translator to provide a solution that changes the transchoice number to an array and translates as per this example:

```
translate.setting: |
    %0%, %1%, %2% and %3%.
    {0}No bananas|{1}One banana|]1.Inf[%count% bananas
    {0}No oranges|{1}One orange|]1.Inf[%count% oranges
    {0}No grades|{1}One kilogram of grapes|]1.Inf[%count% kilograms of grapes
    {0}No apples|{1}One apple|]1.Inf[%count% apples
```

and twig looks like `{{ 'translate.string'|transchoice([4,6,2,3]) }}`

will result in:

> 4 bananas, 6 oranges, 2 kilograms of grapes and 3 apples.

A more complex example is:

```
help: |
    Possible students are limited to the selected !!!form_grade!!! in the course to which this activity belongs. You currently %1% of %0%. Reportable will be set to true if the activity reportable is true.
    {0}no possible students|{1}one possible student|]1,Inf[%count% possible students
    {0}have no students allocated|{1}have one student allocated|]1,Inf[have %count% students allocated
```

Twig

```
{{ 'help'|transchoice([48, 9]) }}
```

results in

> Possible students are limited to the selected Grade in the course to
>   which this activity belongs. You currently have 9 students allocated
>   of 48 possible students. Reportable will be set to true if the
>   activity reportable is true.

So, Question:  Any other solutions for multiple plural translations?

Comment: should more simple splitting all in separate translated string (and more reusable)? Such as `translate.banana.setting` , `translate.orange.setting` etc... My two cents

Comment: Thank @Matteo.  This can result in a lot of duplicated material, and the individual settings can only be prepended or appended to each other.  I need to be able to imbed the translations within the final result..